# Button.setEnabled(true) remains greyed

Tags: android

I have an  Activity which is resumed with

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
            Log.v(TAG, " onResume() disables the OK button");
    // onAuthentificated will re-enable it
    findViewById(android.R.id.button1).setEnabled(false);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Later, the authentification is successful, and my callback is called

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticated(String username) {
    Log.v(TAG, "user can press button");
    findViewById(android.R.id.button1).setEnabled(true);
    super.onAuthenticated(username);
}
```

I know that the `setEnabled(true)` is called last.

My problem is that the button remains greyed out. What's happening and how can I fix this?

The layout(but it won't help)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/VerticalLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- other stuff --> 
    <Button
        android:id="@android:id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@android:string/ok" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here are the last lines of logcat

```
08-30 13:00:45.182: V/ReportActivity(344): onResume() disables the OK button
8-30 13:00:45.382: I/ReportActivity(344): Authentification token callback
08-30 13:00:45.477: D/dalvikvm(344): GC_CONCURRENT freed 324K, 5% free 9960K/10375K, paused 2ms+3ms
08-30 13:00:45.567: D/NetworkService(344): Broadcast the fact user is authenticated
08-30 13:00:45.567: D/ReportActivity(344): user can press button
```

Comment: This happens on a real Galaxy S2 with ICS 4.0.4

Comment: Are you sure that the resource of your button is "android.R.id." and not "R.id"?

Comment: @Keyboardsurfer Godd comment. But, Yes, I usually use `android.R` resources when the View is simple and its role is generic. Also, the button is greyed out, which means `setEnabled(false)` works

Comment: true. Does it happen on other devices as well?

Comment: Add logging in `onResume()`. Maybe `onResume()` is being called both **before** and **after** `onAuthenticated()` is called.

Comment: @Keyboardsurfer It does not happen on emulator/Jelly Beans. (I had to mockup the AccountManager to run this part on the emulator)

Comment: @DavidWasser Good hypothesis, but no, i'm sure setEnabled(true) is called last. I have edited the question with tail of logcat

Comment: Is onAuthenticated called on Ui thread? It usually throws an error, but maybe whoever is calling OnAuthenticated is catching all exceptions

Comment: I would cache the result of `findViewById(android.R.id.button1)` in a field and try again.

Comment: @nandeesh I had a doubt, but I think logcat shows pid `(344)`. Am I correct?

Comment: @mercutio You can promote this comment as an answer with all my thanks :)

Comment: pid should not matter in this case, all threads will run under same pid. What you can try is use runOnUithread.

Comment: @nandeesh onAuthentificate is called by a BroadcastReceiver which is private member from the activity.

Comment: try putting the log after setenabled is called and check the value of isenabled on the button

Comment: @rds Ok, Added it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to store the result of `findViewById(android.R.id.button1)` in a field that is initialized by the `onResume()` method.